# Is this possible to use a variable for an url in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm calling a function like this:

`<?php print get_thumbnail('http://url.com/?skin=rss'); ?>`

Being a php newbie, I'm wondering if there is a way to change the `http://url.com` part based on a custom metadata I have set up in Wordpress. So I guess it would look something like this:

`<?php print get_thumbnail('<?=$video_src?>/?skin=rss'); ?>`

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Someone please fix that title! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have the right idea, you just don't need to re-open PHP tags since you're already inside some. You can use `.` to concatenate (join together) the value of `$video_src` and `"?skin=rss"`.

```
<?php print get_thumbnail($video_src . "?skin=rss"); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php print get_thumbnail($video_src . '/?skin=rss'); ?>
```

Keep in mind that `<?= $foo ?>` is shorthand for `<?php echo $foo; ?>`.  `<?= ?>` won't be expanded in strings, but you can achieve something similar using [double quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double):

```
<?php print get_thumbnail("$video_src/?skin=rss"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, except within PHP, you don't need to enter the PHP tags again.

```
<?php print get_thumbnail($video_src . '/?skin=rss'); ?>
```